# How does (de)activating constraints work internally?

Tags: ios

I noticed that when I activate a constraint, I immediately - at that line of code - get a warning that constraints can't be satisfied simultaneously.

I assumed that layout is calculated at some later point during something like a "UI update cycle", not every time constraint is (de)activated. So in a block of code that (de)activates constraints, one has to be careful about the order, so that the layout is always satisfiable. Is that correct?

Is there some elegant way to rewrite the following code so that it doesn't trigger a warning cause by both constraints being active at the same time?

```
func switchConstraints() {
    constraint1.isActive = flag
    constraint2.isActive = !flag
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to override `updateViewConstraints()`. There you can activate/deactivate your constraints without the warnings.

Along these lines:

```
@IBAction func doUp(_ sender: Any) {
    flag = !flag
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    constraint1.isActive = flag
    constraint2.isActive = !flag
    super.updateViewConstraints()
}
```

Another option would be to activate both constraints, but give them different Priorities. Then change the Priorities instead of activating/deactivating:

```
    // in viewDidLoad, or wherever you created the constraints
    constraint1.priority = .defaultHigh
    constraint2.priority = .defaultLow

    constraint1.isActive = true
    constraint2.isActive = true
```

then, perhaps on button tap:

```
    @IBAction func doUp(_ sender: Any) {
        flag = !flag
        constraint1.priority = flag ? .defaultHigh : .defaultLow
        constraint2.priority = flag ? .defaultLow : .defaultHigh
    }
```